# Magento 2 - How to override magento 2 hash ?

Tags: magento2, migration, password

I'm currently migration from woocommerce to magento 2, the problem is magento and wordpress have different hash engine. there's a way to override magento 2 hash without edit magento core file directly, thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to overwrite the hashing mechanism. There's a lot that can go wrong. It's better to import your customers and tell them to request a new password or show them a reset password form on their login on the new shop.